# SQLite String append in Android?

Tags: android

Below I have mention my code. I want String append but this is not working.

```
public String fetchresturantID(String resturantID)
{
    String query = "select  "+resturantID+" From " + TABLErestaurant;

    mCursor =db.rawQuery(query, null);
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    if (mCursor.moveToNext()) {

        buf.append(mCursor.getString(0));
        String str = buf.toString();
        System.out.println("**************"+str);

    }

   return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: That table more than id is there .I want all id in that column.So i have used in String append.But that's not work for me.

Comment: See this code .i have implement in my class HashMap<String, String> paramsvalue = new HashMap<String, String>(); paramsvalue.put("restaurant_id", dataBase
      .fetchresturantID(DatabaseHelper.columnresturantID));

Comment: I got all data in query but i can't append string

Answer (score 0):

replace your code in this way

```
String s="";
    if (mCursor.moveToNext()) {

        s+=mCursor.getString(0);

        System.out.println("**************"+s);

    }

   return s;
```

Comment: Do mCursor.moveToFirst() before your If statement

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with StringBuffers, you can try a simple approach with a string array, something like this :

```
String str[]= new String[0];
str[0]="0";             
mCursor= db.rawQuery(Query, null);                      
if (mCursor.moveToNext()) {         
str[0]=mCursor.getString(0);
System.out.println("**************"+str[0]);
}
```